# Heroku SMTP can't sending email using

Tags: heroku, smtp, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi i am currently having some problem with sending an email that gives me this error when i do the heroku logs:

```
ArgumentError (An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.):
```

i am currently using Mandrill by MailChimp for my mailer and also this is the code for adding it

```
if current_user.invite @user
  set_activity(current_user, @user, "connection.request")
  FriendshipMailer.requesting(current_user, @user).deliver
  redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "Successfully invited a user"
else
  redirect_to user_path(@user), alert: "Error was encountered"
end
```

anybody can help me with this as idont know what to do also what do i add , as i am fairly new here in rails 4 and is a bit confussed by the commands, any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks!

Comment: Have you set your SMTP From Address?

Comment: provide, please, your mailer and mail settings